# How to make "ReflectionException: Class ..." errors pass PHPUnit 5.7

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit

I have this in my code

```
throw new \Exception('need id and provider');
```

It throws this error in phpunit tests:

> Exception: need id and provider

When I do this:

```
$this->setExpectedException('need id and provider');
```

The error disappears but instead I get this:

> ReflectionException: Class need id and provider does not exist

So I essentially trade one error for another without the backtrace.

Info:

1. I have to use this outdated version of PHP unit.
2. This is a WordPress plugins I test with my own tests build on WP 5.6 PHPUnit tests.
3. This runs on PHP 7.4.14, but I expect this error to fire on all the other versions I intend to test.
4. I read something about`setExpectedException` being deprecated not sure if this matter for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
$this->expectException('Exception');
```

It does not throw errors about empty messages and that is fine by me as I check that in other ways later in the tests anyway. All the things with the deprecated:

```
$this->setExpectedException('Exception'); // complained about empty message.
$this->setExpectedExceptionMessage('Message'); // generated weird errors
```

I tried failed.

Answer (score 0):

`setExpectedException` tells PHPUnit to expect an exception *with the given class name*, but you've given it the *message* of the exception instead. As you mention, it was also already deprecated even in that version of PHPUnit.

The relevant documentation for PHPUnit 5.7 shows the non-deprecated methods in that version: https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions

The right call in your case would be `expectException('Exception')` or equivalently `expectException(\Exception::class)`

To make it check the *message* of the exception, you use the separate method `expectExceptionMessage`.

Comment: thanks but If I set the message as well it tries to call some function inside the class the code I am testing sits `Failed asserting that exception of type "Error" matches expected exception "Exception". Message was: "Call to undefined method Tests_ShortcodeArgValidationErrors::setExpectedExceptionMessage()" at
/...er/tests/tests-sc-errors.php:113

Comment: `equivalently setExpectedException(\Exception::class)` does not work for me. Just `setExpectedException('Exception')`

Comment: I did nothing wrong the way you claimed it will `equivalently` work does NOT in my code. And this did not solved it for me I post how I solve it now.

Comment: Just to be clear the, `::class` notation is just part of PHP, nothing to do with PHPUnit or any particularly application; it's just a convenient habit to get into so you don't have to write out long namespaces. https://3v4l.org/I3e0N No idea why it didn't work for you, most likely a small typo somewhere that you didn't spot.

Comment: Ah, I've realised my mistake with the expect message method. I have updated the answer based on the documentation I'd already linked.

Comment: Yes must have been a typo, it works but wants a message and the message thing generates weird errors see my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry for the confusion.